# Convert Jquery ajax to Coldfusion cfhttp

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

can someone help to convert Jquery ajax to Coldfusion cfhttp.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "something.cfm",
    data: { 'grid': 123 },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var dataContent = 'Success';

    }
});
```

I had tried to convert like:

```
<cfhttp url="something.cfm"
method="POST"
result="objGet">
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="grid" value="123"/>
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml, text/xml, */*" /></cfhttp>
```

But it is not working, can someone please help.

Comment: What higher level objective are you trying to accomplish? You need an absolute path to remote url....not a relative one. Please note that *"is not working"* is not a proper technical problem description that tells anyone anything of value

Comment: is "something.cfm" on your current server? if so cfhttp is not the way to go.
If it's not, use the full url: url="http://mysite.my/something.cfm"